# No suitable user-defined conversion from <class> to multimap

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++. I was trying to create a class similar to `multimap`, called `multimap_viewer`. I would like to be able to convert my `multimap_viewer` to a `multimap`, but I just don't know how. I have tried to write an assignment operator, but it's not working. Could someone point me out in the right direction, please?

Code to demonstrate the error:

```
multimap_viewer<std::string, std::string> m_view;
std::map<std::string, std::string> mymap;
mymap[ "this" ] = "that";
m_view.add( mymap );

std::multimap<std::string, std::string, string_size_less> a = m_view;
```

The error I receiving in the last line is:

> no suitable user-defined conversion from "multimap_viewer<std::string, std::string>" to "std::multimap<std::string, std::string, string_size_less, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>>" exists

My *wannabe* working assignment operator:

```
template <class T, class V>
class multimap_viewer
{
  public: 
  std::multimap<T, V, class Comp, std::allocator<std::pair<const T, V>>>& operator=(multimap_viewer<T, V> mv)
  {
    std::multimap<T,V, class Comp, std::allocator<std::pair<const T, V>>> mp;
    // copy items and stuff
    return *mp;
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't write a custom assignment operator, but a [conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you can't overload assignment of the destination type in general in C++.
That utilized syntax doesn't even mean that (it is still assigning on to `multimap_viewer`).

The best you can do, as the comment said, is to write a conversion function.
If you can, make it `explicit` also.

(code not tested)

```
template <class T, class V>
class multimap_viewer
{
  public: 
  /*explicit*/ operator std::multimap<T, V, class Comp, std::allocator<std::pair<const T, V>>>() const{
    std::multimap<T,V, class Comp, std::allocator<std::pair<const T, V>>> mp;
    // copy items and stuff
    return mp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Making it `explicit` would defeat the purpose of using it in the assignment.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, but that is not necessarily a good thing. Conversion could still happen by more explicit means. e.g. `std::multimap<...> a{m_view};`.